# How to know which headers are included without looking at the preprocessed code in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, compiler-options

I've got some big **C** programs, and I would like to know when I'm compiling this program, which header files are actually included...

The simplest solution would be to print the preprocessed code and look but do you know if there's a way to compile and at the same time showing what header files are included?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [-M option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#dashMF) to output the dependencies. Use [-MD](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-MD-830) to generate *and* compile. Use -MF to redirected to a file.

Also -MM allow ignoring the system file in the dependencies list.

```
gcc ... -M  -MF <output_file>     # generate dependencies
gcc ... -MD -MF <output_file>     # compile and generate dependencies
```

Comment: but from the manual : Passing -M to the driver implies -E, and suppresses warnings with an implicit -w. 
So the program is not actually compiled

Comment: Yes, you have to use -MD to compile *and* generate the dependencies at the same time.

Comment: These days (I don't know whether it applied in 2009), you can use `-H` too.  This presents the header files in a hierarchy, so you can see which header included which others, to arbitrary depths.  This can sometimes be informative — especially if your project uses `../somedir/someheader.h` notations either directly in `#include` lines or via `-I` options on the command line.  The same file can be included by multiple different paths.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-MD` option - see `man gcc` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Increase gcc verbosity and then run it through an own made filter program?

Answer (score 0):

Use gcc -M or gcc -MM. Adjust the output with sed if you like. If you use GNU make (and you should) you can wrap this up a into single tidy command.